# What is compared in ''than I thought''?

Tags: comparisons

Let's take a sample sentence:

*This game is funnier than I thought.*

We compare the game. The game is funny, but not as I thought first.
We are trying to find what is compared to the game.

Comment: there, "than I thought" could be paraphrased "than I expected [it to be]"

Comment: This is a good question, but not for this site. Ask it here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

> The game is funnier than I thought.

That is,

> The game is funnier than the assumed/imagined game in my mind before I actually experienced the actual game.

Comment: The game was funnier than I thought [it was]. it was is implied.

Comment: @Lambie More "The game was funnier than I thought [it would be]"

Comment: could be either: thought it would be or thought it was. The point is one of those is implied.

Answer (score 2):

Its meaning is:

*The game is x funny; I thought it would be y funny; x > y.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your own question. You thought the game was one thing, but it is not. It is funnier. You are comparing two different opinions about the game.